# selenium stand alone is not starting

Tags: java, selenium

getting below error while running selenium stand alone server :

```
E:\pradhan_workspace\Baaza1Core\Baaza1AngularWebV1>webdriver-manager start
webdriver-manager: using global installed version 12.0.6
[11:53:23] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\agudla.BHUVIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chromedriver_2.33.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users\agudla.BHUVIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v0.19.1.exe -jar C:\Users\agudla.BHUVIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.0.jar -port 4444
[11:53:23] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 6744
Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile C:\Users\agudla.BHUVIS\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.8.0.jar
[11:53:24] I/start - Selenium Standalone has exited with code 1
```

Comment: **`selenium-server-standalone-3.8.0.jar`** location please.

Answer (score 0):

**selenium-server-standalone-3.8.0.jar** is not official. The [official website](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) is providing download link of latest version as 3.7.1. Download this and then try restarting your standalone server.